# LIKE SQL-query on an array using Peewee

Tags: python, postgresql, peewee

I have a PostgreSQL table that has a column with an array of tags (an array datatype in the tags column). Using Peewee (the python ORM), I would like to select all rows where any of the tags matches a part/substring of any string in a list.

So, for example, I could have a list that looks like this:

```
["stan", "tina"]
```

and that should match all rows in the table that has any of the tags `afghanistan`, `pakistan`, `stanford` or `argentina`.

The SQL query could look something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM media WHERE tags::text LIKE ANY (ARRAY[‘%stan%‘, ‘%tina%‘]);
```

How would I do this using Peewee?

The `tags` column is modelled like this:

```
tags = ArrayField(TextField)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

assuming your model looks like

```
from peewee import Model, TextField
from playhouse.postgres_ext import ArrayField


class Media(Model):
    tags = ArrayField(TextField)
```

creating subquery with array field [unnested](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/functions-array.html)

```
from peewee import fn

subquery = (Media.select(Media.id.alias('id'),
                         fn.unnest(Media.tags).alias('unnested_tags'))
            .alias('subquery'))
```

generating tags filter like

```
tags = ["stan", "tina"]
tags_filters = [subquery.c.unnested_tags.contains(tag) for tag in tags]
tags_filter = reduce(operator.or_, tags_filters)
```

and final query will be

```
query = (Media.select().join(subquery,
                             on=subquery.c.id == Media.id)
         .filter(tags_filter)
         # gets rid of duplicates
         .group_by(Media.id))
```

*P. S.*: in **Python 3** `reduce` function is available at [`functools` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.reduce) while in **Python 2** it is a [built-in](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#reduce)

Comment: Hi! I only get your example work when a whole tag is matched. I guess that could be because the `tags` model is an `ArrayField(TextField)`, so the `contains()` only checks if the array has an exact match of the tag, not a substring. (I edited the question to clarify the case: The column type is `ArrayField(TextField)`.)

Comment: nah, it still just matches full tags. When looking in the SQL produced by Peewee, `contains_any()` results in `WHERE t1."tags" && %s)`, and the `&&` means that both arrays needs at least one identical value. In my case, the `tags` list contains substrings/parts, not the full tags. So the tag "istanbul" is not matched by having "stan" in the tags list, atm...